# Create an agent where only some messages get responses?

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

Is it possible to create a mailbox agent that only sometimes posts replies?  From the looks of it, It seems to me that you have to always send an async reply channel if you want to ever post replies.

For my use case I'd really like to be able to have the flexibility that some messages only need to be delivered to the agent, whereas other messages I'd like to get either a synchronous or asynchronous reply back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly - but you can certainly use a discriminated union as a type of your messages. Then you can have some cases (message types) that contain `AsyncReplyChannel<T>` and some other messages that do not carry it (and do not require a reply).

For example, for a simple agent that adds numbers, you can have `Add` (which does not need response) and `Get` which does need a response. In addition, `Get` carries a Boolean that specifies whether we should reset the state back to zero:

```
type Message = 
  | Add of int
  | Get of bool * AsyncReplyChannel<int>
```

The agent then receives messages repeatedly and if the message is `Get` then it sends a reply:

```
let counter = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> 
  let rec loop count = async {
    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
    match msg with 
    | Add n -> return! loop (count + n) // Just update the number
    | Get (reset, repl) ->
        repl.Reply(count)               // Reply to the caller 
        let count = if reset then 0 else count // get new state
        return! loop count }            // .. and continue in the new state
  loop 0 )
```

You can then use `Post` method to send message that does not require a reply and `PostAndReply` to send a message that returns something via an async reply channel:

```
counter.Post(Add 10)
counter.PostAndReply(fun r -> Get(true, r))
counter.PostAndReply(fun r -> Get(false, r))
```

Comment: I guess I was tripped up in the examples on msdn that aliased the message with an async channel tuple. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Can you maybe add an example when you would pass data along with the Get?  Lets say you wanted to pass an ID along and have the agent reply to that. For example if Get was `Get of int * AsyncReplyChannel<int>`

Comment: Actually I got it, I just create the union type when posting for the response.

Comment: @devshorts I added another argument to the `Get` message to show how that would work...

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I appreciate the extra effort!  I ended up doing this too. What had caused me confusion was sort of the way I was building this app out, I just needed to acknowledge that I can't generalize the multiple post functions into one of the same type.